# Playing text to speech at scheduled points in the background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background, text-to-speech

I need to play speech at scheduled points after that app has closed, and have tried using the following code to achieve this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10) {
        print("here")
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Test speech")
        utterance.rate = AVSpeechUtteranceDefaultSpeechRate
        self.synthesizer.speak(utterance)
}
```

in the applicationDidEnterBackground() function in the App Delegate, but it only works with smaller numbers of seconds like 2, but not 10.

How do I play speech once the app enters the background?

Thanks.

Comment: There must be a way since google maps does it when you've asked for directions and then go to another app.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this (at least not legitimately on a non-jail broken device). Your App gets 5 seconds of activity in the background and then gets suspended (except in a few circumstances, and playing text to speech won't count IMHO):

> When your app moves to the background, the system calls your app delegate’s applicationDidEnterBackground(_:) method. That method has five seconds to perform any tasks and return. Shortly after that method returns, the system puts your app into the suspended state.

(From [Apple Docs "Extending Your App's Background Execution Time"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/managing_your_app_s_life_cycle/preparing_your_app_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time))